# Low voltage beak away/tension release connectors for building to building overhead cables

Tags: safety, low-voltage, overhead

Are there low voltage breakway or tesion release connectors that should be used for overhead, building to building applications?

The background is we are running a single pair of speaker cable, and a single pair for relay input from one building to another building that is accross an access road.  Generally the speaker cables get screwed down on a terminal strip as are the wires to the relay contact.  The terminal is also the conection for wires that go to critial equipment.

The overhead cables that run accross the streat are high, but it is conceavable that they could get snagged by an unusually high truck, or caught in a tree fall.  In that case there seems to be chance that the cable would rip the terminal board, and other critical equipment off the wall, unless there is something between in that gives first.  Kind of like a fuse for tension.

Anyways, I'm sure there's something for this, but I've never seen it, and can't find it with a google search.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need breakaway connectors. I think you just need to provide strain relief near the PCB and screw terminals such that the wire will break before it pulls out. Look at what is done with overhead electrical wire at the point of entry into the house.

Comment: You might consider safety stds with masts and higher wires, a flag or banana plugs with restraints . But it may tangle traffic. Also install Grammarly.  Or go wireless

Comment: what is your plan in a lightning storm event?

Comment: @jsotola I've seen a couple of lighning suppresion options that I'm looking into. I haven't gotten too deep but products like this -> https://www.juicegoose.com/products/l-series/la-series might do the trick.

Comment: You could install any kind of in-line connector that does not have a locking mechanism, such as ordinary 0.1" pitch DuPont connectors, and it will *probably* unplug harmlessly when that truck comes through.